# Appending to cell array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, types

I am new to matlab. I have one question about datatypes.

I have an array of the `cell array` type. In the variables window it shows me it as `190x1 double`.

I have two questions.

1. What is the purpose of the `cell array` type if there is the `matrix` type ?
2. How to append another similar array to the column of an existing array. For example I have two arrays `190x1 double` I wan't a new array to be `380x1 double`

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd encourage you to browse the documentation for [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).  One of the most common uses as it states is mixed size or mixed type data...among other uses.

> Cell arrays commonly contain either lists of text strings,
>   combinations of text and numbers, or numeric arrays of different
>   sizes.

To append two arrays you could do this.  It will place the two vectors end to end.

```
X=ones(190,1);
X =[X; X];
```